# Removing everything after pattern with sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

I know there are lots of questions about it but I can't get it working.

I want to clean a group (for instance `root`) in `/etc/group` with `sed` or `awk`. So I need to delete everything after `root:*:0:`

I tried to remove it with:

```
cat /etc/group | awk '!p;/^root:*:0:/{p=1}'
```

and

```
cat /etc/group | sed 's/root\:\*\:0\:.*//'
```

but `sed` removes the whole `root` line.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you say `everything after` do you mean a) everything after that string on  the line containing it, or b) every line in the file after the line containing that string, or c) everything after that string on the line containing that string plus every line after it, or d) something else? Is the `*` in your example supposed to be literal or the regexp repetition metachar? Please [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output to help clarify your requirements and give us something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an address with sed to limit what lines to act on:

```
 sed '/^root:/s/:[^:]*$/:/' /etc/group
```

Which, for the line(s) starting with `root:`, removes all characters after the last `:` in the line.

(`/etc/group` records only have 4 `:`-delimited columns, so it strips the last one with all the group members in it)

Comment: That would modify lines starting with `root:foo:bar`, not just lines starting with `root:*:0:` as the OP says they want.

Comment: @EdMorton `/etc/group` is extremely unlikely to have more than one root group, and it's not going to look notably different (Mine is `root:x:0:`; I wonder what OS uses an asterisk for the password field).

Comment: I wasn't imagine them having more than one root group, rather that they only want to modify the one they have if it looks like they specified.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the question whether this should really be done using simple text-processing tools, your `sed` call clears the entire line because the "substitute" command replaces *the entire* found pattern with the replacement (in your case the empty string).

The minimal modification to get your `sed` line to work would be to write

```
sed 's/root:\*:0:.*/root:*:0:/' /etc/group
```

or, using capture groups,

```
sed 's/\(root:\*:0:\).*/\1/' /etc/group
```

(and btw, `cat` is never necessary when using `sed` or `awk`, just provide the file as command-line argument).

The solution presented by @Shawn is however more elegant in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=":"} $1=="root"{$NF=""} 1' /etc/group
```

Split fields on `:` and set the last field to an empty string if the first field is `root`.